# RaspberryPi 4 as NAS with disks in USB hub

Tags: pi-4

I would like to build a simple home NAS hosting 4 discs on RaspberryPi and I wanted to use [Quad SATA HAT](https://wiki.radxa.com/Dual_Quad_SATA_HAT), however they are either completely out of stock worldwide, or discontinued :(

Next viable option to me seems [4x USB HUB HAT](https://www.waveshare.com/usb-3.2-gen1-hub-hat.htm), but I am concerned about the speed, since it's attached to RaspberryPi via just one USB (as opposed to SATA HAT, which uses both USB 3.0). If I connect four 2.5'' discs to this HAT and use external power (HAT has separate USB-C) will this setup reach it's full potential? My calculations say mostly yes, as HDDs won't deliver more than 150MBps, times four is around 4800Mbps, which should be fine for 5Gbps USB3).

Comment: What will it be used for?  What are the odds that all 4 disks are going to be fully utilized at the same time?

Comment: @rtaft Disks will be in raid, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have deluded yourself with respect to USB performance. Even USB 3.0 on the RPi 4 is much less than your "calculations" suggest - as shown in the following graph from a [*promotional* piece in the MagPi blog](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks). Other aspects of the RPi 4 design suggest that the figures shown below are optimistic for most use-cases. You may also wish to consult other test/reviews/reports: [1](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/raspberry-pi-4-ssd-test,39811.html), [2](https://www.martinrowan.co.uk/2020/06/raspberry-pi4-usb3-0-storage-performance/) of the RPi 4B's USB3 performance. Or, if you're into rather extreme hardware modifications of your RPi, you may [improve performance by using the PCIe bus](https://domipheus.com/blog/raspberry-pi-4-pci-express-it-actually-works-usb-sata-gpu/) instead of USB 3.

[image]

Comment: The PCIe only supports 4Gbs and all of the USB ports share it.  The issue here is that both HATs are falsely advertising their potential.

Comment: @rtaft: [*"On 29 November 2011, PCI-SIG preliminarily announced PCI Express 4.0, providing a 16 GT/s bit rate that doubles the bandwidth provided by PCI Express 3.0, while maintaining backward and forward compatibility in both software support and used mechanical interface. PCI Express 4.0 specs also bring OCuLink-2, an alternative to Thunderbolt. OCuLink version 2 has up to 16 GT/s (8 GB/s total for ×4 lanes), while the maximum bandwidth of a Thunderbolt 3 link is 5 GB/s. "*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#PCI_Express_4.0)

Comment: I should have clarified that the USBs share a single lane of the PCIe according to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=261373.  The first HAT seems to suggest 10Gbps by using a dual USB 3 link but the dual link doesn't buy you more speed.  As you said, you need to do hardware modifications to access more lanes.